# Repeat input events

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have one InputText which on clicking a button leads to several events (e.g. 4). On Clicking button,

- Event 1 happens and gives output to buffer 1. On checking buffer 1 is filled,
- Event 2 happens and gives output to buffer 2. On checking buffer 2 is filled,
- Event 3 happens and gives output to buffer 3. On checking buffer 3 is filled,
- Event 4 happens.

That is the Events only occurs if the previous buffer is filled. Else its in Event=0 mode.

How do I do this in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an .setOnClickListener() on the inputText, and when inputText is clicked you do the code in that section. After that code has run you can call another event, and do this as many times as you want.

Put these in the OnCreate method:

```
EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextname);
inputText.setOnClickListener(action1);
```

After OnCreate, put:

```
public void action2 () {
    //action 2 code here
    //add other actions here

}
View.OnClickListener action1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {
        //action 1 code here
        action2();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Comment: Suppose I need to do an addition to the EditText how do I do that? I used this: out1.setText(enter.getText()); now I need to perform an addition (lets say 2) add 2 to the entered value at EditText.

Comment: you're just trying to perform addition on the inputted value? In the example in my answer you can just do

Comment: int num = inputText.getText()

Comment: and then do the addition on num and then inputText.setText(num); sorry for the multiple comments.

Comment: Thanks NyW i could do it. I was actually looking for syntax to do add, mul, sub, less than, greater than etc in android Studio.

Comment: You can just use java commands in the java files. All the syntax for those can be found at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/math-operators-and-math-class.html